# How to change the width of css tab according to length of alphabet?

Tags: html, css

It's a tab menu of css. I tried to write a long name in one tab so its out its position 
you can check the images on following links:

This is the orignal one:
 [image: http://innovativeartz.com/problems/orignal.png]

When I changed in css
[image]

```
.tabs {width:100%;overflow:auto;}
.tabs li {float:left;padding-right:1px;}
.tabs .end {padding:0}
.tabs a {display:block;width:66px;font-size:13px;line-height:31px;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);position:relative;background:url(../images/tabs_bg.gif) bottom repeat-x #3081c8;text-decoration:none;p}
.tabs a:hover, .tabs .active {background:url(../images/bg_form.gif) repeat}
.tabs_cont {border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;-moz-border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;-webkit-border-radius:0 0 4px 4px;behavior:url(js/PIE.htc);position:relative;background:url(../images/bg_form.gif) repeat;padding:30px 35px 28px;width:1000px;height:500px;}
```

and this is the HTML

```
 <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" id="changeText">inclusive Class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="changeText2">inclusive Class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="changeText3">inclusive Class</a></li>
        <li class="end"><a href="#" id="changeText5">inclusive Class</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Please any one help me out how to look its original bit with long text?

Comment: The parent of the li's is not wide enough.

Comment: so can you please give me the perfect code Mr.Pankucins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is that your `ul` (tabs) is in `article.col` which has a width of `267px` so when you say `100%` for `ul` `width` it expands only that much.

make it 1000px.

also remove the `tabs` `a` width.

Comment: still not proper

innovativeartz.com/problems/again.png

Comment: @dani1 can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: well go to jsfiddle.net left upper code gets your html, right upper corner gets your css. thats it. you don't need the javascript @dani1 run the code. than hit save and send the link

Comment: on browser it is doing problem :(

Comment: it looks fine. except the left side seems like has been cropped

Comment: @dani1 do you have a link to your page?

Comment: wait let me give you a link

Comment: @dani1 an easy fix is change tabs css width to 1000px;

Comment: the reason is that your ul is in article.col which has a width of 267px so when you say 100% it expands only that much

Comment: Thank you very very much post this as a answer so i give repution thanks again

Comment: how to make this tab width more longer?

Comment: @dani1 it should automactically grow

Comment: @dani1 or you can change tabs li width to something larger

Comment: yes but i want to center the text and drop 1px from left and right so its look like innovativeartz.com/problems/orignal.png

Comment: @dani1 one great tool for css is firefox. if you right click on the element and click inspect element you can change the css and find out whats wrong easily

Comment: yes but would you please tell me how to center this text as in image?

Comment: you want to center the tabs @dani1

Comment: its already centered i think but you can add text-align:center to the li

Answer (score 0):

`article.col1` is the problem . It has a fixed `width` defined..just increase it to `100%` and you will have it working like before